# Args not being recognized anymore - Discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I recently found out my arguments are not being recognized anymore when running a command.
If I don't put args my console logs `undefined`, but when I put args it doesn't log anything.

My command handler :

```
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");

module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
  const commandFolders = readdirSync(`./Commands/`);
  for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commands = readdirSync(`./Commands/${folder}`).filter((files) =>
      files.endsWith(".js")
    );
    for (const file of commands) {
      const command = require(`../Commands/${folder}/${file}`);
      client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
  }
};
const {
  Client,
  Message,
  MessageEmbed,
  Collection,
  PermissionFlagsBits,
} = require("discord.js");
const { PREFIX } = require("../../config.json");
const User = require("../../Models/User");

module.exports = {
  name: "messageCreate",
  /**
   * @param {Client} client
   * @param {Message} message
   */
  async execute(message, client, Discord) {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) || message.author.bot) {
      return;
    }
    const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ + /);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const command =
      client.commands.get(commandName) ||
      client.commands.find(
        (cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName)
      );
    if (!commandName) return;
    if (!command) return;

    if (command.bloxia && message.guild.id !== client.config.BLOXIAID) return;
    if (command.developer && !client.config.DEVID.includes(message.author.id))
      return message.reply({
        content: ":x: This command is only available to developers.",
        ephemeral: true,
      });
    let user = client.userSettings.get(message.author.id);
    // If there is no user, create it in the Database as "newUser"
    if (!user) {
      const findUser = await User.findOne({ Id: message.author.id });
      if (!findUser) {
        const newUser = await User.create({ Id: message.author.id });
        client.userSettings.set(message.author.id, newUser);
        user = newUser;
      } else return;
    }
    if (client.maintenanced && !command.maintenancebypass)
      return message.reply(":x: Maintenance mode is on !");
    if (command.premium && user && !user.isPremium) {
      return message.reply({
        content: `> \`${message.author.username}\` You are Not Premium User`,
      });
    }

    if (command.owneronly && message.author.id !== client.config.OWNERID)
      return message.reply({
        content: ":x: This command is only available to the owner.",
        ephemeral: true,
      });

    command.execute(message, args, commandName, client, Discord);
  },
};
```

If you have any problems understanding some part I'm willing to explain so ask away !
There are also a bunch of definitions for certain requirement but ignore them really (if command.`...`) etc..

I tried replacing `args[0]` (the method used to call args) in a command's code with `args[1]` but it didn't change.

Comment: What intents have you enabled?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I enabled Guilds, GuildMembers, GuildMessages, MessageContent and GuildMessageReactions in my code and on dev portal message content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space in the regex.
Use this fixed code

```
const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/);
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't see that ! Probably just missclicked sometime...